# Arduino interrupt not called using PinChangeInterrupt

Tags: arduino-mega, sensors, interrupt

I am new to Arduino and I was trying to figure out how to use an interrupt. When I ran this it would read my magnet but the interrupt would never be called and I couldn't figure out if anyone can help me that would be great.

Thanks.

Here is the code

```
#include <PinChangeInterrupt.h>

//#define INTERRUPT_PIN 12
#include <Math.h>

#define RADIUS 3
const int hallPin = 7; // the number of the hall effect sensor pin
const int ledPin =  13; // the number of the LED pin
// variables will change:
int hallState = 0; // variable for reading the hall sensor status
double inital_val = 0.0;
double distance = inital_val;

void setup() {
  // initialize the LED pin as an output:
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(hallPin, INPUT);
  //attachInterrupt(hallPin, calc_distance, HIGH);
  // initialize the hall effect sensor pin as an input:
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(hallPin), calc_distance , HIGH);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  //read the state of the hall effect sensor:
  hallState = digitalRead(hallPin);
  if (hallState == LOW) {
    // turn LED on:
    Serial.print("Main Loop: HallState LOW\n");
    digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
    Serial.print(distance, 2);
    Serial.print("\n");
  } else {
    Serial.print("Main Loop: HallState HIGH\n");
    // turn LED off:
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
  }
}

void calc_distance() {
  Serial.print("INTERRUPT! \n");
  if (digitalRead(hallPin) == HIGH) {
    Serial.print("YES!\n");
    distance += PI * 2 * RADIUS;
  } else {
    Serial.print("NO!\n");
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure hallPin=7 has an interrupt on your particular board?  Unos interrupt on 2,3 only.

Answer (score 1):

The attachInterrupt function is only for normal interrupts. Read the reference: [attachInterrupt](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/attachInterrupt)

When you need the Pin Change Interrupts, there is a library for that: [EnableInterrupt](https://github.com/GreyGnome/EnableInterrupt)

Try to keep the interrupt routine as short as possible. Do not use the Serial functions in calc_distance because the Serial functions themself use also interrupts.

The Arduino Mega does not have 'double' floating point variables, the compiler changes it into 32-bit 'float' variables. You are reading the interrupt pin for a test ? I don't understand why you do that. Please make "distance" a volatile variable. In the loop function, the interrupts should be turned off when reading "distance". Because "distance" is a 4 bytes 'float' variable and the Arduino Mega is a 8-bits microcontroller. An interrupt could occur when the "distance" is only read for a part from memory.

Comment: Yes to moving the serial stuff out of the interrupt, but attachInterrupt should be able to handle pin changes just fine.  Maybe  `attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(hallPin),calc_distance , RISING);`  or `attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(hallPin),calc_distance , CHANGE);` would be better than whenever it is HIGH.

Comment: The attachInterrupt function is only for pin 2 and 3 for an Arduino Uno, according to the reference. Because it uses the normal interrupts. The special "Pin Change Interrupt" (PCINT) requires specific code or a library. When a library is used, the functions from that library should be used for the interrupt. This code seems to use a little of both.